# Connecting to Snowflake with SSMS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssms

Can someone let me knkow if it's possible to connect to Snowflake database with SSMS?

At the moment, the only way to connect snowflake database/warehouse is either within snowflake workspace or via Visual Studio Code.

If it's not possible to connect to snowflake database with SSMS, can someone let me know if there are any other methods than the methods I've just describled?

I installed the ODBC driver Alex suggested, but when try to add the Snowflake driver, its not be found, see image.
[image]

Do I need to reboot laptop?

OK, thanks to @Alex I can now connect
[image]

But how do I query the `MYSCHEMA.HEALTHCARE_CSV` table?

I updated the security policies as follows:

[image]

But when if I try to execute a query, I get the following:
[image]

Comment: You can connect via DBeaver.This is official and is supported by Snowflake.

Comment: **SQL Server** Management Studio (SSMS) is for *SQL Server*; it does not work with other (R)DBMS products,

Comment: [SQL Development & Management](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ecosystem-editors)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked server in Microsoft SQL Server to connect to Snowflake, using the Snowflake ODBC driver. There are some steps here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

For more ways to connect, you can check: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ecosystem

EDIT:
Can you try the 64-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator and see if you see the Snowflake Driver there?

Comment: Hi @Alex, DBeaver is the way to go... but thanks anyway